# How to customize hover-template on with what information to show

Tags: python, plotly, dataset, hover, plotly-python

Here is my dataset:

[image: my demo dataset]

After locking my dataframe by *year*  and grouping by *month*, I proceed with calculating percentage increase/decrease as a new column; it ends up looking like this:

[image: printing 3 dfs]

Now for my Plotly plot I use this to display traces and add some hover info:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=group_dfff.Months, y=group_dfff.Amount, name=i,
                        hovertemplate='Price: $%{y:.2f}'+'<br>Week: %{x}'))
```

Now as you can see there is an argument `hovertemplate` where I can pass my x and y... However, I can't figure out how to include my **PERC_CHANGE** values in it too.

**Question**: How to include other wanted columns' values inside the `hovertemplate`? Specifically, How do I include **PERC_CHANGE** values as I shown desired output below:

[image: desired hover template output]

I solved my specific problem, check pic below (adding 3rd element it is, please see comments), however question remains the same as I do not see how to do this for 4th, 5th and so on elements.
[image]

Comment: So I figured my problem out for this specific scenraio... I had to add `'<br>%Change: %{text}'` and specifying in the brackets `text=group_dfff.PERC_CHANGE` - this worked as I wanted. However, **text** var is a builtin thingie so I am still not sure how would I go about adding let's say forth, fifth and more labels that I would want to have upon hovering the datapoint...

Answer (score 103, accepted):

For Plotly Express, you need to use the `custom_data` argument when you create the figure. For example:

```
fig = px.scatter(
    data_frame=df, 
    x='ColX', 
    y='ColY', 
    custom_data=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
)
```

and then modify it using `update_traces` and `hovertemplate`, referencing it as `customdata`. For example:

```
fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "ColX: %{x}",
        "ColY: %{y}",
        "Col1: %{customdata[0]}",
        "Col2: %{customdata[1]}",
        "Col3: %{customdata[2]}",
    ])
)
```

This took a lot of trial and error to figure out, as it isn't well-documented, and the inconsistency between the `custom_data` and `customdata` is confusing.

Comment: When I was trying just now, I don't know why `custom_data` argument will remove all of the columns involved (in your case is Col1, Col2, Col3) to be displayed on the chart.

Comment: Man plotly is cool, I just wish they designed documented the API a bit more carefully. Thanks a lot for sharing this!

Answer (score 16):

I've actually had the similar problem, and trust me it took me 2 and a half hour to figure out. Let's understand with an example.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1,cols=2,subplot_titles=('First plot','Second plot'),
                   specs=[[{'type': 'scene'}, {'type': 'scene'}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[0,1,2,3],y=[0,1,2,3],z=[0,1,2,3]), row=1,col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[0,1,2,3],y=[0,1,2,3], z=[0,1,2,3]), row=1,col=2)

fig.update_layout(title='Add Custom Data')

fig.show()
```

This will create simple two scatter3d plots, where hoverdata is x,y and z axis. Now you want to add the data `m=[9,8,7,6,5]` to first plot. you can parse `m` in `text` argument and add `hovertemplate` as well.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[0,1,2,3],y=[0,1,2,3],z=[0,1,2,3],
                          text=[9,8,7,6], hovertemplate='<br>x:%{x}<br>y:%{y}<br>z:%{z}<br>m:%{text}'), row=1,col=1)
```

This should work just fine. But now we want to add one more list say `n=[5,6,7,8]` to the first plot (or any). We will use `customdata` argument this time.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[0,1,2,3],y=[0,1,2,3],z=[0,1,2,3],
                          text=[9,8,7,6],customdata=[5,6,7,8],
                          hovertemplate='<br>x:%{x}<br>y:%{y}<br>z:%{z}<br>m:%{text}<br>n:%{customdata}'), row=1,col=1)
```

Now what if we want to add our 3rd list of custom data. Here comes the tricky part. You cannot parse the list of two lists in the custom data, and then call `customdata[0]` and `customdata[1]`, it's not that simple. our 3rd list is `k=[2,4,6,8]`.

We need `customdata=[[[5],[2]],[[6],[4]],[[7],[6]],[[8],[8]]]` like this and it should work fine. Basically we need to give plotly a single list (or array) where in each element it's the list of all points you want to show.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[0,1,2,3],y=[0,1,2,3],z=[0,1,2,3],
                          text=[9,8,7,6],customdata=[[[5],[2]],
                                                     [[6],[4]],
                                                     [[7],[6]],
                                                     [[8],[8]]],
                          hovertemplate='<br>x:%{x}<br>y:%{y}<br>z:%{z}<br>m:%{text}<br>n:%{customdata[0]}<br>k:%{customdata[1]}'), row=1,col=1)
```

We almost done, but there is one thing left. It's lots of work to manually create list like we given in customdata, therefore we'll automate it using powerful library `import numpy as np`

```
n = [5,6,7,8]
k = [2,4,6,8]

nk = np.empty(shape=(4,2,1), dtype='object')
nk[:,0] = np.array(n).reshape(-1,1)
nk[:,1] = np.array(k).reshape(-1,1)
```

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[0,1,2,3],y=[0,1,2,3],z=[0,1,2,3],
                          text=[9,8,7,6],customdata=nk,
                          hovertemplate='<br>x:%{x}<br>y:%{y}<br>z:%{z}<br>m:%{text}<br>n:%{customdata[0]}<br>k:%{customdata[1]}'), row=1,col=1)
```

BOOM !
You can parse `df['Column name']` in place of `np.array(n)` if you want to add data directly from dataframe.

Answer (score 9):

Similar to the above, but I prefer to do the command all in one go, to use DataFrames all the way through, and to stick with Plotly rather than Plotly Express:

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=group_dfff.Months,
        y=group_dfff.Amount,
        customdata=group_dfff.PERC_CHANGE,
        name=i,
        hovertemplate='<br>'.join([
            'Price: $%{y:.2f}',
            'Week: %{x}',
            'Percent Change: %{customdata}',
        ]),
    )
)
```

Note also that if you have multiple "custom data" fields (e.g. "A" and "B") in your DataFrame you'd like to include in the hoverdata, you can slightly modify the above to include as much data as you'd like:

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=group_dfff.Months,
        y=group_dfff.Amount,
        customdata=group_dfff[['A', 'B']],
        name=i,
        hovertemplate='<br>'.join([
            'Price: $%{y:.2f}',
            'Week: %{x}',
            'Field A: %{customdata[0]}',
            'Field B: %{customdata[1]}',
        ]),
    )
)
```

Comment: Any way to use proper dict keys and not some dangerous int ordering thing? js version allows this properly in the plotly.graph_objects stuff so it must be possible

Comment: @mathtick Kinda.  JS arrays are ordered but Python dicts are not, and AFAIK the interface layer only accepts HTML. You'd have to do a bit of work to make it happen, and it would end up being a bit clunkier than I prefer for what is essentially a static string - especially if you want to distinguish between DF columns and human-friendly labels, potentially-different formatting for each field in the `hovertemplate`, etc.  If you anticipate doing this on a regular basis with different dataframes, traces, format options, etc... write a custom function which builds the `go.Scatter()` instance.

Comment: I had a similar problem - thanks for the solution! And just as an addition - this code shows all selected columns and their values in a hover: 
`hovertemplate="<br>".join([f"{col}: %{{customdata[{idx}]}}" for idx, col in enumerate(selected.columns)])` where `selected` is a selection of the original `pd.DataFrame`

Answer (score 5):

You can add custom data to hovertemplate as :

```
hovertemplate = 'Price: $%{customdata[0]:.2f}'+'<br>Week: %{customdata[1]} ' 
+ '<br>Change: %{customdata[2]}'
```

where `customdata` can either be your `group_dfff` or even some other totally different data frame from which you want to fetch data for your hover info.

Here is the [link](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#adding-other-data-to-the-hover-with-customdata-and-a-hovertemplate) to the documentation on plotly.