# Python & Plotly: Adding Hover Data to Density Heat Map

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

As a trivial example, I'm using the first heat map shown on the [Plotly 2D Histograms](https://plotly.com/python/2D-Histogram/) webpage. The [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.density_heatmap.html) references the hover_data parameter but I'm unable to display additional data. The data frame in the example include these columns:

```
>>> df.columns
Index(['total_bill', 'tip', 'sex', 'smoker', 'day', 'time', 'size'], dtype='object')
```

According to the said documentation, hover data, such as "size" can be added like this:

```
>>> fig = px.density_heatmap(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", hover_data=['size'])
>>> fig.show()
```

However, the generated plot only shows "total_bill", "tip", and "count" in the hover data. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely a bug with `px.density_heatmap`. After running `fig = px.density_heatmap(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", hover_data=['size'])`, the hovertemplate should include the `size` column, but hovertemplate string doesn't include the correct information.

```
fig.data[0].hovertemplate
'total_bill=%{x}<br>tip=%{y}<br>count=%{z}<extra></extra>'
```

For the sake of comparison, if we run: `fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", hover_data=['size'])`, we can see that the hovertemplate does include the `size` column embedded in the customdata:

```
fig.data[0].hovertemplate
'total_bill=%{x}<br>tip=%{y}<br>size=%{customdata[0]}<extra></extra>'
```

You probably need to use Plotly `graph_objects` for the time being to display additional df columns in your heatmap when you hover. I can circle back on this answer to show you if you would like!

Comment: I used this [SO issue/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057881/python-plotly-how-to-customize-hover-template-on-with-what-information-to-show) as a reference for a solution. I will answer my own question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This is apparently not really a bug. See https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3419

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Derek's suggestion and this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057881/python-plotly-how-to-customize-hover-template-on-with-what-information-to-show), I used `hover_template`, `graph_objects`, and `customdata` to plot the data but the custom hover data for the "Smokes" field is not displayed.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px


df = px.data.tips()

fig = go.Figure(
    data=go.Histogram2d(
        x=df['total_bill'], 
        y=df['tip'],
        z=df['size'],
        histfunc='sum',
        customdata=[df['smoker']]
    )
)

fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate='<br>'.join([
        'Bill $: %{x}',
        'Tip $: %{y}',
        'Size: %{z}',
        'Smokes: %{customdata[0]}'
    ])
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Did this work as intended for you?

Comment: No. The hover text is displayed as literal text: "Smokes: %{customdata[0]}". I raised an issue on [GitHub](http://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3419). See their response.